# Split by the delimiter that comes first, Python

Tags: string, python-2.7, parsing, logfile

I have some unpredictable log lines that I'm trying to split.

The one thing I can predict is that the first field always ends with either a `.` or a `:`.

Is there any way I can automatically split the string at whichever  delimiter comes first?

Comment: random question: do they use . or : for anything other than field separators... if not you could do line.replace('.',":').split(":")

Comment: the rest of the fields are completely unpredictable, i'm getting all kinds of different stuff.

Comment: fair enough... I just figured I'd offer a possible one liner; answers below are obviously more complicated but a bit more robust in the face of less predictable data

Comment: oh, thanks.  wish i could come up with one liners but I haven't developed those skills yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the index of the `.` and `:` characters in the string using the `index()` function.

Here’s a simple implementation:

```
def index_default(line, char):
    """Returns the index of a character in a line, or the length of the string
    if the character does not appear.
    """
    try:
        retval = line.index(char)
    except ValueError:
        retval = len(line)
    return retval

def split_log_line(line):
    """Splits a line at either a period or a colon, depending on which appears 
    first in the line.
    """
    if index_default(line, ".") < index_default(line, ":"):
        return line.split(".")
    else:
        return line.split(":")
```

I wrapped the `index()` function in an `index_default()` function because if the line doesn’t contain a character, `index()` throws a ValueError, and I wasn’t sure if every line in your log would contain both a period and a colon.

And then here’s a quick example:

```
mylines = [
    "line1.split at the dot",
    "line2:split at the colon",
    "line3:a colon preceded. by a dot",
    "line4-neither a colon nor a dot"
]

for line in mylines:
    print split_log_line(line)
```

which returns

```
['line1', 'split at the dot']
['line2', 'split at the colon']
['line3', 'a colon preceded. by a dot']
['line4-neither a colon nor a dot']
```

Comment: Your answer seems like an excellent solution to the problem.  I'm going to try this out now and let you know how it works.

Comment: Outstanding!  Passed my log through the function and it works great!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Check the indexes for both both characters, then use the lowest index to split your string.

Comment: Good idea.  So like ```period = mystring.index('.')``` ```colon = mystring.index(':')``` ```if period < colon: mystring.split('.') else: mystring.split(':')```  I'll try this.